# Создание условия для запроса поиска

Tags: sql

Возможно ли создать критерий поиска в виде условия? Сталкиваюсь с различными запросами типа:

1. Наименование начинается с гласной, заканчивается на согласную;
2. Начинается на гласную, но не может содержать больше гластных в наименовании;
3. Начинается на согласную и не может иметь больше 1 гласной.

В целях борьбы с копипастом и раздуванием запроса ищу способы унификации критериев отбора. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Каждое показанное элементарное условие (а показанные условия состоят из нескольких элементарных) легко программируется. Соответственно любое условие есть комбинация нескольких элементарных. Определяешь нужные элементарные, определяешь условия комбинирования, динамически строишь текст запроса - и выполняешь.

Comment: @Akina Програмируя можно собрать условия в один объект и передать его в метод. В SQL у меня не получается это сделать и приходится заниматься переборкой в ручную, что вызывает потерю времени и простыню копипаста.

Comment: Например, *Наименование начинается с гласной* в терминах SQL выглядит (с точностью до диалекта) как `name LIKE '[уеыаоэяию]%'`. Аналогично формализуются и все остальные элементарные условия. Они собираются в секции WHERE в одно условие логическими операторами.
`

Comment: name LIKE '[уеыаоэяию]%' - для каждого условия пишется одинаковое условие. Другой пример - Имя начинается и заканчивается на гласную - 6 гласный букв, 36 вариантов перебора. Как я себе представляю унификацию - помещение всех [aoeiyu] в переменную vowels и Sql запрос превратится в WHERE NAME LIKE 'vowels%' AND NAME LIKE '%vowels'

Comment: А почему не собирать запрос динамическим SQL, есть условие добавили, нет, пропустили пошли к следующему.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov вы говорите про Declare, exec?

Comment: Судя по вашему профилю, вы знакомы с C# и EntityFramework. Нет ли возможности использовать EF (или любую другую linq-подобную ORM) для составления таких запросов? С помошью linq можно довольно удобно комбинировать сложные условия.

Comment: Уточните, какую именно БД используете. И я тоже поддержу вопрос про динамический sql.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov MS Sql. В Linq можно совершать передачу переменных в условие поиска. По диалогу с комментаторами вопроса я нагуглил методы динамического T-SQL в виде объявления условий, как DECLARE NAME varchar(100) и судя по всему это именно то, что мне нужно. Более подробно в https://habr.com/post/272807/

Comment: Лучше это прочтите: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Comment: А если есть интерес, как такое (и можно ли вообще) сделать на linq+ef, то создайте новую тему с соответствующими метками.